# How to import js file to view component angular2

Tags: angular

I want to import js to component and not import js to project. Please help me. I try to this, but not succes.[image]

Detail: I want to import file js: dataTables.bootstrao4.js, dataTables.fixedHeader.js,... (files js in image below) to component in single module and not import to index html.

Comment: please explain more about what you want to do

Comment: I'm not sure if this is angular "2", or just angularjs ( 1.x ). Please elaborate your question more clearly

Comment: Ok, I edited this post. I hope you understand and help me.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want to load libraries only when user moves to some  particular page. If you are working in angular2 read following article

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html